# Different values of same variable in class

Tags: c++, class, templates

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
template<class T>
class vee
{
   T* v;
   int size;
   public:
   vee(int m)
   {
       v = new T[size=m];
       cout<<size<<"\n";
   }
   vee(T* a)
   {
       cout<<size<<"\n";
       for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
       {
          v[i]=a[i];
       }
   }
};
int main()
{
  int x[]={1,2,3};
  int y[]={2,3,4};
  vee<int> v1(3);
  v1=x;
  return 0;
}
```

Why i am getting 2 different values of "size" ?
I have created a constructor to intilize the parameter size and it shows correct value in first constructor but it throws a garbage value in the second constructor ,why??

Comment: One constructor initialises `size` (well, assigns to it) , the other doesn't.

Comment: once initialised how it's value is changed??

Comment: Thanks got it

Answer (score 0):

> Why i am getting 2 different values of "size" ?

`vee(T* a)` is called [converting constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor). When you write something like `v1=x;`, array `x` decays to a pointer, then it is converted to `vee` with provided converting constructor.

`v1=x;` is as if you wrote `v1=vee<int>(x);`

As you can see a temporary instance is created with undefined size and pointer, which is bad. Then you assign this instance to `v1` which is worse.

If you do not want this autoconversion in the future, declare your constructor explicit

`explicit vee(T* a)`

Comment: Got it , Thanks for help

Answer (score -1):

When doing v1=x, you actually go and create new object, since you have not overrided the '=' operator.

Answer (score -2):

> but it throws a garbage value in the second constructor ,why??

```
   vee(int m)
   {
       v = new T[size=m]; // in this constructor you set size
       cout<<size<<"\n";
   }
   vee(T* a)
   {
       // but in this constructor you don't set size
       cout<<size<<"\n";
       for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
       {
          v[i]=a[i];
       }
   }
```

So, when you create a `vee` using the second constructor - and read from `size` - your program has undefined behaviour.